# Android Studio is already running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-jetpack

I enabled Navigation in Android Studio

> File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences on Mac), select the
>   Experimental category in the left pane, check Enable Navigation
>   Editor, and then restart Android Studio.
>   Note: There is no restart button so I exit Android Studio

After that when I start. But nothing shows up. I restart again. Nothing shows up. So I navigate to the /bin directory and did `./studio.sh' that's when the terminal told me Android Studio is already running.  Any ideas how to force it to restart so that I can actually start seeing something? Right now it's in invisible mode.

Answer (score 1):

run below commands:

```
 ps -ax     //list processes info and find android studio PID
 kill xxx   //kill android studio process
```

then restart android studio.